# C# DateTime toString behaves differently on windows server 2012 and 2016

Tags: c#, datetime, iis, webforms, locale

I have the same instance of an application on a windows server 2012 and another on a windows server 2016, But in 2012 version, C# `toString('yyMMddHHmmss')` on DateTime object behave differently than 2016 version !

Here is the log of `toString` I get in 2012 server:

```
Info Culture is: fa-IR 
Info UiCulture is: fa-IR 
Info transactionTime: 181217145529
```

and here is the output of 2016 version:

```
Info Culture is: fa-IR 
Info UiCulture is: fa-IR 
Info transactionTime: 970926140801
```

I should note that the control panel setting in region section for both of the systems are identical, I have no idea what is happening with the 2012 version ! any help is much appreciated.
The Identity of the application pool of both servers are set to `ApplicationPoolIdentity` and registery key of `International` located here `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International` is set to `en-US` for both servers.

Edit:
Here is the example source code of my usage of `toString`

```
var date = transactionTime.ToString("yyMMddHHmmss")
```

Comment: Can you please show your code as well? What you get and what do you expect? Sometimes culture settings even change over windows server (which probably effected by .NET Framework version).

Comment: Are you sure this is for the same `DateTime` value? Seems like the 2012 version is for December 17th 2018, while the 2016 is for September 26th 1997.... If it's for `DateTime.Now`, make sure both servers have the same time and date.

Comment: Looks like one is using the Gregorian calendar and the other is using the Hijri calendar. To convert from Hijri to Gregorian, you add 621 or 622 (depending on the exact date). If you add 621 to 97 you get 718, the last two digits of which are 18 which is what you are seeing.

Comment: Start by hard coding a date and seeing what the result is on both machines. If it is different, we have a locale related issue. If it's the same on both machines, it's going to be something else going wrong.

Comment: @SonerGönül I edited the question to include the code

Comment: @ZoharPeled That old date is today's date in persian calendar

Comment: Can you use the overload of `ToString()` which takes a specific culture to ensure you're using the correct locale?

Comment: @MatthewWatson `toString` behaves differently based on application locale, What has confused me is that in 2012 version of code, it does not respect to locale at all! The system I am working on has been up for a few years, This upgrade to 2016 version has made this problem.

Comment: @MatthewWatson That is another solution but that required changing more than tens of transactions

Comment: @rm-rf I had no idea. Though my grandmother was born in Iran I have never used the Persian calendar. If that is the case, this is probably a problem with local settings.

Comment: It could be that the 2012 version is running on an OS which is a non-Persian version which has had its locale changed to Persian - which would mean that by default threads run in the non-Persian locale. (Or perhaps that's the other way around...)

Comment: A possible solution is to put this at the start of your program (and at the start of any new thread which uses the locale): `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;`

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly specifying cultureinfo :

```
DateTime transactionTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
Console.WriteLine(transactionTime.ToString("yyMMddHHmmss", new CultureInfo("fa-IR")));
Console.WriteLine(transactionTime.ToString("yyMMddHHmmss", new CultureInfo("en-GB")));
```

This will guarantee correct behavior of string format.